# Can I use web-bluetooth to connect with devices with regular BT, NOT BLE?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, web-bluetooth, angular-pwa

I want to build a PWA with capability to connect with "regular" bluetooth, not with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). Is that possible ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Web Bluetooth API currently only supports the GATT (Generic Attribute Profile) portion of the Bluetooth specification, which is primarily used by Bluetooth Low Energy devices. It does not support other Bluetooth profiles.

My team maintains the Web Bluetooth specification and its implementation in Chromium-based browsers as well as work on bringing new capabilities to the web. What type of Bluetooth Classic device are you interested in integrating with a PWA?

Comment: Dear Grant, I had similar issue. In my case I need integrating a Bluetooth Serial Port Profile (SPP) device with PWA. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653422/bluetooth-connectivity-using-pwa

Comment: Hello, thanks for the clarification. We need to integrate with a [livestock stick reader](http://www.allflexusa.com/our-products/readers/product/rs420-series-stick-reader), which uses the Bluetooth® Serial Port Profile (SPP) protocol. Any chance to aggregate this to the API, in the future ? That would save my life ! Best regards.

Comment: Serial port support in general would solve for many more use cases, in addition to just Bluetooth.  There are a ton of devices that connect via serial port.

Comment: The Chrome team is currently experimenting with implementing [the Serial API](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6577673212002304). This will allow access to any serial port recognized by your operating system. For Bluetooth SPP this means that if the device has been paired at an OS level and thus has had a virtual COM port device created then it will work with this API.

Comment: https://crbug.com/1043300 can track adding only BT-SPP, exposed via Serial API.  If there are examples of other classic Bluetooth profiles needed, please speak up on both that issue / the alternative https://crbug.com/1001933 indicating what other profiles are needed.

Comment: Dear @ReillyGrant could you visit my question here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67947790/difficult-to-connect-thermal-printer-via-web-bluetooth
thanks so much before.

Comment: The Chromium team still has not implemented this in Chrome for Android. Are we out of options for Android if we want to connect a regular Bluetooth device with SPP to our Android tablet?